# Redis Transaction rollback

Tags: redis, hiredis

I am new to redis. I have an application in which i have multiple redis commands which makes a transaction. If one of them fails does redis rollback the transaction like relational databases ? Is it users responsibility to rollback the transaction ?

Comment: Might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76807035/3042856

Answer (score 8):

Redis does not rollback transactions like the relational databases does.

If you have a relational databases background, the fact that Redis commands can fail during a transaction, but still Redis will execute the rest of the transaction instead of rolling back, may look odd to you.

However there are good opinions for this behavior:

- Redis commands can fail only if called with a wrong syntax (and the problem is not detectable during the command queuing), or against keys holding the wrong data type: this means that in practical terms a failing command is the result of a programming errors, and a kind of error that is very likely to be detected during development, and not in production.
- Redis is internally simplified and faster because it does not need the ability to roll back.

Check it  out **[`Why redis does not support rollback transactions`](http://redis.io/topics/transactions)** from the documentation and from [**here**](http://openmymind.net/You-Cant-Rollback-Redis-Transaction/) .

Answer (score 1):

[Documentaion](http://redis.io/topics/transactions) here. Redis does not supports rollback.